# error: Private access in class

Tags: java, class

```
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee
{
    private int shift;
    private double rateOfPay;
    private double hoursWorked;

    ProductionWorker(String name, int id, int shift, double rateOfPay, double hoursWorked)
    {
        super(name, id);
        this.shift = shift;
        this.rateOfPay = rateOfPay;
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }



public class TeamLeader extends ProductionWorker
{
    private double monthlyBonus;

    TeamLeader(String name,int id, int shift, double rateOfPay, double hoursWorked, double monthlyBonus)
    {
        super(name, id , shift, rateOfPay, hoursWorked);
        this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;

    }

    public double calcPay()
    {
        double pay = 0;
        //night shift
        if (shift == 2)
        {
            pay = ((hoursWorked + hoursWorked / 2) * rateOfPay) + monthlyBonus;
        }
        else
        {
            pay = (hoursWorked * rateOfPay) + monthlyBonus;
        }
        return pay;
    }
}
```

I extend the class ProductionWorker to class TeamLeader then create a method calcPay() on the class TeamLeader my problem is I need to get the value of variable shift, hoursOfWorked and rateOfPay from the class ProductionWorker so i can use the method calcPay() to my main.Can anybody help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Add getter and setter for your vatiables it `ProductionWorker` and use that for the access to the variables.

Comment: Do you know what `private` means, or did you use it because someone told you to?

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to the variables of parent class (ProductionWorker), you need to change the variable scope from private to protected.

Private variables are visible only within the class.
Protected variables are visible in subclasses and to all classes within the package

You may refer to this link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

If you do not wish to set them as protected, you can create getters and setters for the variables too, but that is not the preferred way to go.

eg of getter and setter:

```
private int shift;

protected int getShift() {
    return this.shift;
}

protected void setShift(int shift) {
     this.shift = shift;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your fields are private that means that unless you create a method that returns the particular value you are looking for when the Object is instantiated, none of your other classes or their methods will be able to access that data, hence it being private.

What you need to do is create "getter" methods in your `ProductionWorker` class that will allow you to say something like this in your `TeamLeader` class:

```
shift = ProductionWorker.getShift();
```

These sorts of methods are specifically designed so that if you need to look at the fields of the Object from a different class, you can simply create the object and use its method to return the value. Here is what these methods should look like:

```
public int getShift()
{
    return shift;
}

public double getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}

public double getRateOfPay()
{
    return rateOfPay;
}
```

By putting these public methods in your superclass, you will be able to create a ProductionWorker in your `TeamLeader` subclass and use its methods to access the instance variables.

**UPDATE** 
Here is some sample code that may work for your cause:

```
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee
{
    private int shift;
    private double rateOfPay;
    private double hoursWorked;

    ProductionWorker(String name, int id, int shift, double rateOfPay, double hoursWorked)
    {
        super(name, id);
        this.shift = shift;
        this.rateOfPay = rateOfPay;
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    }

    // Now we can add the "getters"
    public int getShift()
    {
        return shift;
    }

    public double getHoursWorked()
    {
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public double getRateOfPay()
    {
        return rateOfPay;
    }



public class TeamLeader extends ProductionWorker
{
    ProductionWorker prodWorker = new ProductionWorker(Jared, 10046, 2, 8.50, 12.6); // Creates a production worker you can reference

    private int shift = prodWorker.getShift();
    private double rateOfPay = prodWorker.getRateOfPay();
    private double hoursWorked = prodWorker.getRateOfPay();
    // These three statements demonstrate the getters and how they can be implemented

    private double monthlyBonus;


    TeamLeader(String name,int id, int shift, double rateOfPay, double hoursWorked, double monthlyBonus)
    {
        super(name, id , shift, rateOfPay, hoursWorked);
        this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;

    }

    public double calcPay()
    {
        double pay = 0;
        //night shift
        if (shift == 2)
        {
            pay = ((hoursWorked + hoursWorked / 2) * rateOfPay) + monthlyBonus;
        }
        else
        {
            pay = (hoursWorked * rateOfPay) + monthlyBonus;
        }
    return pay;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this may not be the perfect solution for your entire project, as I cannot see the other superclass you are extending from or what your client should do with this code. This sample code is just meant to give you an idea of how getters work in classes that make Objects and demonstrate how they can be used. I would definitely keep the getters I set for you.

**Also**
Make sure that for every instance variable you have for an Object, you should have a getter for each one. You will find you might need to access that data from time to time to make calculations in a client.

Comment: im sorry but im new in java, how can i add getter method to my productionworker?

Comment: Inside the bracket that encapsulates your `ProductionWorker` class you would add them like you add constructors. I will update my answer to show you example code.

Comment: No problem. Objects are strange things to get used to.